# How to Add button shadow in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

This code is not working.,..

```
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 12,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.58,
shadowRadius: 16.00,

elevation: 24,
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I noticed you've already implemented `elevation` when I re-formatted your original question. I'll still leave this answer + example here.

*Could you provide more code so we could spot the actual error?*

---

There's nothing wrong with your code as such. However, **Android** requires `elevation: 1` for shadows in order to work.

See https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/shadow-effect for details.

Answer (score 0):

It's crucial to add borderRadius in order for shadow to appear.
Also you may need to add some margin if you have elements right after the button without any space between them